# Refactoring two similar if loops with slightly different values (Java)

Tags: java, refactoring

```
public boolean hasCapturableEnemy(Piece[][] board, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {

    //If the Pawn belong to the Upper Team (Faces downward)
    if(board[startX][startY] != null && board[startX][startY].getTeam() == Player.UP) {
        //If a Piece exists on a diagonally adjacent tile, return true
        if(startX - endX == -1 && Math.abs(startY - endY) == 1) {
            if( (board[startX + 1][startY - 1] != null && board[startX + 1][startY - 1].getTeam() != Player.UP) || 
                    (board[startX + 1][startY + 1] != null && board[startX + 1][startY + 1].getTeam() != Player.UP)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } 

    if(board[startX][startY] != null && board[startX][startY].getTeam() == Player.DOWN) { 
        //If the Pawn belongs to the Down Team (Faces upward)

        if(startX - endX == 1 && Math.abs(startY - endY) == 1) {
            //If a Piece exists on a diagonally adjacent tile, return true
            if( (board[startX - 1][startY - 1] != null && board[startX - 1][startY - 1].getTeam() != Player.DOWN) || 
                    (board[startX - 1][startY + 1] != null && board[startX - 1][startY + 1].getTeam() != Player.DOWN)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

I have this function that contains two similar if statements that is kind of hard to refactor.

I am saying this because these two share significant portion of duplicated codes but because of the part where differs slightly like board[startX + 1][startY - 1] and board[startX - 1][startY - 1], I find it difficult to refactor it efficiently.

In other words, I can surely refactor this by creating another function that contains the common parts, but I am afraid of creating few more if loops inside that function and making the code dirtier.

Any advice for refactoring this kind of code?

Comment: If this code works, please ask on [codereview.se].

Comment: An if statement is not a loop

Comment: For one thing, you can reorder the checks, so that you only check `if(startX - endX == 1 && Math.abs(startY - endY) == 1) {` once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set a multiplier variable to `1` or `-1` depending on which way is "up", and then multiply against that variable any time you're offsetting your "X" values.

Something like this should work, I think:

```
if(board[startX][startY] == null) {
    return false;
}

Player player = board[startX][startY].getTeam()
int xOffset = player == Player.UP
    ? 1
    : -1;
//If a Piece exists on a diagonally adjacent tile, return true
if(endX - startX == xOffset && Math.abs(startY - endY) == 1) {
    if( (board[startX + xOffset][startY - 1] != null && board[startX + xOffset][startY - 1].getTeam() != player) || 
            (board[startX + xOffset][startY + 1] != null && board[startX + xOffset][startY + 1].getTeam() != player)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

And there's some further refactoring you could do, capturing `board[startX + xOffset]` in a variable to make things even cleaner.